# SMIL to CSS Animation: multiple animations on single element

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, svg-animate, smil

Now that [SMIL is dying](https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/) I want to convert my simple animated SVGs to using CSS Animations, but I am not super sure how to do the mapping. In this specific svg there are *two* animation elements.

```css
#embedded {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
   <svg id="embedded"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="rgba(43,43,43,0.3)" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round"/>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="502"/>
            <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="150.6 100.4;1 250;150.6 100.4"/>
        </circle>
    </svg>
```

While I seemingly started out fine with these css rules I quickly got stuck

```
stroke-dasharray: 150.6 100.4 1 250 150.6 100.4;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
stroke-dashoffset: ?;
```

What would a complete mapping be like? Is it possible at all? [Sara Soueidan](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) says not all animations are possible using CSS that are possible using SMIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is how you'd convert that SMIL animation into its equivalent CSS animation:

- Both your `animate` tags have the `dur="2s"` and so the CSS animation's duration (`animation-duration`) would also be `2s`. You can either specify this value using the long-hand property or using the short-hand property like in the below snippet.
- There is no `calcMode` attribute specified for your `animate` element and so the interpolation mode is `linear`. Since the interpolation mode is `linear`, the `animation-timing-function` will also be `linear`.
- The `repeatCount` is `indefinite` and so the `animation-iteration-count` will be `infinite`.
- For the `stroke-dashoffset`, the animation has only a from (0%) and a to (100%) value. So, in the CSS animation's keyframes, we specify the `stroke-dashoffset` as `0` (`from` value) at `0%` and as `502` (`to` value) at `100%`.
- For the `stroke-dasharray`, the animation makes use of ***values*** instead of just `from` and `to`. In this case, there are three semi-colon separated values and so the first value from the list is given within the `0%` keyframe , the second value from the list is given at `50%` keyframe and the last is given within the `100%` keyframe selector.

```css
#embedded, #embedded2 {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#embedded circle#animated {
  animation: demo 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes demo {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 150.6 100.4;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1 250;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 502;
    stroke-dasharray: 150.6 100.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="embedded" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="rgba(43,43,43,0.3)" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" id="animated">
  </circle>
</svg>

<svg id="embedded2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="rgba(43,43,43,0.3)" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="502" />
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="150.6 100.4;1 250;150.6 100.4" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're welcome @oligofren. Happy to help. By the way, I read recently that even Chrome is reconsidering their decision about deprecating SMIL animations. So maybe all is not lost yet :)